# One of the computers on my home network does not get a local IP

Tags: ssh, lan

My ethernet-connected ubuntu box and my wirelessly connected lap both have 192.168... addresses. I just plugged a second ubuntu box into the router, but it gets an 84.210... address. I can ssh to it from the others, but not to any of them from it. What's going on?

Comment: try runnnig `dhclient <interface>` on the second ubuntu box. Please post `ifconfig` output and `route -n` output in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It seems like your second Ubuntu box has received an external IP address for some (uncertain to me) reasons. And in this case it's not surprising that ssh to your other PCs doesn't work - without port forwarding set up on the router it can't reach the machines which are in the local subnet.*

Unfortunately, some important details are missing, especially this: **did it work previously in the same configuration?**

- If no, try to plug your "second box" into another port on your router and then reboot the box.
- If yes: first try to reboot the router and the "second box"; if this doesn't help, try to remember any changes that were made since the last time it worked.

Hope this helps.

Comment: plugging into a different hole and rebooting the router worked. thanks!